# Merging of ETL files has failed (0x80071069) (Flags: 0x0000001f)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to profile my application using the built-in profiler in Visual Studio 2017:

[image]

However when I close the application, this is what appears:
[image: Microsoft Visual Studio was unable to create a diagnostics report. Check Output window for errors.]

This is what I see in output window:

```
Profiling of 'MyProjectName' started.
MyProjectName has exited.
Profiling of 'MyProjectName' stopped.
Diagnostics session stopped with errors.

Merging of ETL files has failed (0x80071069) (Flags: 0x0000001f).
```

What's wrong? I am running MS Visual Studio Community 2017 on Windows 7 x64. I am profiling C++ Qt application.

Comment: 0x80071069 = ERROR_WMI_INSTANCE_NOT_FOUND, so the tracing session was not found. maybe it uses ETW providers that are not available in Windows 7 and only win8 or newer.

Comment: That is ERROR_WMI_INSTANCE_NOT_FOUND, "The instance name passed was not recognized as valid by a WMI data provider".  Hmm, that's not good.  Somebody claimed that running low on disk space is an underlying cause.  Seems a bit remote, but profiling certainly eats a lot of it.  Leaks temp files like a sieve too. So run the cleanup wizard first.  If you've been considering "time to update this old dog", now would be a good time :)

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue with that exact same error code 0x80071069.  I noticed my `WMI Performance Adapter Service` (wmiApSrv) was stopped.  Starting it back up resolved my issue and I was able to successfully profile my application.

In the past I had seen a similar error caused by my C: drive running low on space due to the size of the temp trace files.  Make sure you have plenty of free space in your C drive as well.