# Merging of ETL files has failed (0x80070070) (Flags: 0x0000011f)

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2017, profiling

Trying to profile my command line application in VS 2017 on a W10 machine with April 2018 Update, VS fails to create the report.

The UI says `Microsoft Visual Studio was unable to create a diagnostics report. Check Output window for errors`.

The Output window says

```
Profiling of 'Program' started.
Program has exited.
Profiling of 'Program' stopped.
Diagnostics session stopped with errors.

Merging of ETL files has failed (0x80070070) (Flags: 0x0000011f).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Previous search gives little answers as to why, but the problem seems related to Windows' event logging service. Comments on [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44802946/8695112) suggest it's related to disk occupation, but with no source. My SSD is indeed almost full, but with 6 GB of free space.

I resolved the issue, the multiple times it happened, by restarting windows and then start the profiling as first thing as the OS is ready. On a fresh start it works, but going further with changes and profiling it eventually appears again.

If someone knows a long-term solution feel free to add.

Answer (score 2):

Code 0x80070070 "There is not enough space on the disk."  Your disk was full, or became full during a build or other operation as temporary files were created.